Clickhouse - How to correctly design tables that collect events
I have my clickhouse listen to 2 rabbitMQ queues - for simplification let's call them events_requests and events_results.
the data in each of them looks something like this:
CREATE TABLE events_requests_queue(
    eventId Int64, -- A serial generated id that is unique across the entire system
    sentTime Datetime64,
    eventType LowCardinalidy(String)
) ENGINE RabbitMQ ...

CREATE TABLE events_results(
    eventId Int64, -- same unique id across the entire system
    endTime Datetime64,
    handlerId int64, -- Which service handled the event
    result LowCardinalidy(String)
) ENGINE RabbitMQ ...

So my question is when creating the tables how should I choose the sorting key.
My initial thought was that because most of my queries are filtering the sentTime or endtime, and grouping the eventType, result or handlerId it will be smart doing something like this:
CREATE TABLE events_requests(...) 
ENGINE MergeTree Order By (toStartOfDay(sentTime), eventType, eventId)

CREATE TABLE events_results(...) 
ENGINE MergeTree Order By (toStartOfDay(endTime), result, handlerId, eventId)

Which indeed gave me good results for most of my queries but is seems to preform really bad for queries that are joining the tables based on the eventId.
So my question is what should I do differently? should I add a projection on eventId? or make my sorting key based on only eventId and add skipping indexes for all the other columns? This will probably work good on the time columns (since there is a good correlation between id and time) but not on other columns.
I also thought about creating another materialized view for their join but I read that these views only updated by the left side of the join and I cant rely on that (because sometimes the results are inserted to db before the request)
Is there something else I might do get a good performance on both the regular queries and on the joins?

look https://kb.altinity.com/engines/mergetree-table-engine-family/pick-keys/
and please keep in mind you need to CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW which will poll engine=RabbitMQ table and insert data into engine=MergeTree table

Well they mostly talk about the case of filtering which I have done and it worked fine, my problem is when I am doing join on a column that is not in my sorting key
